# latlng.lat show NaN in google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am implementing the Google Maps API, i need to do is that when I click on the map should capture the coordinates, longitude and latitude in separate fields of text, ie an input display length and another input latitude of moment could capture the coordinates and clicking but when I check with console.log (latlng.lat); NAN shows the value while console.log (latlng.lng); works well for showing me coordinate properly.

when i add in file .js this line: var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

show this error:  Uncaught Eb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Eb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap:131:73"}

please help me.

HTML:

```
<div id="map-wrapper">
    <div id="floating-panel">

      <label>latitud y longitus juntas:</label>
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">

      <label>latitud</label>
      <input id="latitud" type="text" value="">

      <label>Longitud</label>
      <input id="longitud" type="text" value="">

      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
  </div>
      <div id="map"></div>  
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

JS:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 20,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map, infowindow) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(latLng);

  console.log('la latitud y longitud inicial  son: '+ latLng);
  jQuery('#latlng').val(latLng);
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  console.log('la latitud y longitud nuevas son: '+ input);
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
  console.log('la longitud real es: '+ latlng.lng);
  console.log('la latitud real es: '+ latlng.lat);
}
```

Comment: Can you try `console.log(latlngStr[0]);` after you define `latLngStr`, this might give you a hint.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi, @Deepak Kamat, It displays the latitude but a sign of brackets "(" at the beginning and just want the coordinates

Comment: @nashCode, that's the issue, you need to get rid of the "(" for it to be parsed correctly using `parseFloat`. I think this has already been answered. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input.split(',', 2);` returns:

```
0:"(37.4419"
1:" -122.14190000000002)"
```

The 0th entry is not a number.

```
input = input.substring(1,input.indexOf(')'));
var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
console.log('longitude: '+ latlng.lng);
console.log('latitude: '+ latlng.lat);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m3cyrrov/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  placeMarkerAndPanTo(map.getCenter(), map, infowindow);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map, infowindow) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(latLng);

  jQuery('#latlng').val(latLng);
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;

  input = input.substring(1, input.indexOf(')'));
  console.log(input);
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]),
    lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])
  };
  console.log('longitude: ' + latlng.lng); //this work fine
  console.log('latitude: ' + latlng.lat); // this show NAN       
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="latlng" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```